# Generated MSIL throws "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

I'm trying to write dynamic method that make a clone of the Dictionary<,>.
Code presented below throws Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at Clone(Dictionary`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at MsilTests.DynamicHelper.Clone[TKey,TValue](Dictionary`2 source) in x:\MsilTests\MsilTests\DynamicHelper.cs:line 17
   at MsilTests.Program.Main(String[] args) in x:\MsilTests\MsilTests\Program.cs:line 11
```

This exception occurs when i added line:

```cs
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, enumeratorType.GetMethod("MoveNext"));
```

I have no idea why this Exception is thrown.
If someone can help solve this problem, I will be very grateful.

```cs
    public static class DynamicHelper
    {
        public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Clone<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
        {
            var type = typeof (Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof (TKey), typeof (TValue));
            var genericFunc = typeof(Func<,>);
            genericFunc = genericFunc.MakeGenericType(type, type);
            var method = new DynamicMethod("Clone", type, new[] { type }, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule, true);
            GenerateMsil(method, type);
            return (Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)method.CreateDelegate(genericFunc).DynamicInvoke(source);
        }

        private static void GenerateMsil(DynamicMethod method, Type type)
        {
            var genArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
            var keyType = genArgs[0];
            var valueType = genArgs[0];
            var pairType = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
            var enumeratorType = typeof(Dictionary<,>.Enumerator).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
            var enumerableType = typeof (IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(pairType);

            var generator = method.GetILGenerator();

            var labelRet = generator.DefineLabel();
            var labelEndFinally = generator.DefineLabel();
            var labelMove = generator.DefineLabel();
            var labelWhile = generator.DefineLabel();

            var source = generator.DeclareLocal(type);                  //local_0
            var target = generator.DeclareLocal(type);                  //local_1
            var enumerator = generator.DeclareLocal(enumeratorType);    //local_2
            var pair = generator.DeclareLocal(pairType);                //local_3
            var key = generator.DeclareLocal(keyType);                  //local_4
            var value = generator.DeclareLocal(valueType);              //local_5

/*Stack   */
/*[0]     */
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, target);
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, source);
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, source);
/*[1] -1+1*/generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, type.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, enumerator);

            var tryFinally = generator.BeginExceptionBlock();
            // try {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, labelMove);
            generator.MarkLabel(labelWhile);

/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, enumerator);
/*[1] -1+1*/generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, enumeratorType.GetProperty("Current").GetGetMethod());
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, pair);

/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, pair);
/*[1] -1+1*/generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, pairType.GetProperty("Key").GetGetMethod());
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, key);

/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, pair);
/*[1] -1+1*/generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, pairType.GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod());
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, value);

/*[2] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, target);
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, key);
/*[3] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, value);   
/*[0] -3  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, type.GetMethod("Add"));

            generator.MarkLabel(labelMove);
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, enumerator);
/*[1] -1+1*/generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, enumeratorType.GetMethod("MoveNext"));
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, labelWhile);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Leave_S, labelRet);
            // } finally {
            generator.BeginFinallyBlock();
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, enumerator);
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, labelEndFinally);
/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, enumerator);
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, enumeratorType.GetMethod("Dispose"));
            generator.MarkLabel(labelEndFinally);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Endfinally);
            // }
            generator.EndExceptionBlock();
            generator.MarkLabel(labelRet);

/*[1] +1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, target);
/*[0] -1  */generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
    }
```

**Update**:
Thanks to all for help and attention to my problem.
I've already solved the problem, it consists in using Ldloc with Dictionary<,>.Enumerator, however Dictionary<,>.Enumerator is a value type and it's important to use Ldloca to pass address of local variable into the Call or Callvirt.
I updated source with correct code.

Comment: Just a quick try: have you tried using call instead of callvirt?
Also, is the return value of "enumeratorType.GetMethod("MoveNext")" correct? (Not null, bind to the correct method, etc?)

Comment: I've tried Call, Callvirt - same result. "enumeratorType.GetMethod("MoveNext")" returns valid MethodInfo.

Comment: In cases like this, it's often very useful to generate the code to an assembly and then PEVerify that. It will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I verified assembly with PEVerify.exe (/md /il options) - all OK. I think this is useful because IL generated in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

`GetEnumerator` should use `CallVirt`. At the bottom you have:

```
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, enumerator); // +1
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, enumeratorType.GetMethod("MoveNext")); // -1+1
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, target); // +1
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // should be 0 if void, or 1 for non-void
```

That is two values on the stack, which you haven't popped. There should only be one.

Remove the call to `MoveNext` if you aren't going to use it; which means you also need to remove the `Ldloc` before it.

The following works (but doesn't do anything interesting):

```
// Create instance of Dictionaty<,>
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
// Store instance in local variable "target"
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, target);
// Load first method argument to the stack (for static method - argument, for non-static - instance for with method called)
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
// Store argument in local variable "source"
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, source);
// Load value of local variable "source" to the stack
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, source);
// Call method GetEnumerator of type IEnumerable<> 
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, type.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
// Store value returned from method in local variable "enumerator"
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, enumerator);

generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, target);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

It is, however, semantically equivalent to:

```
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

(but without leaking an enumerator)

Comment: Im going to use MoveNext. I update code with Callvirt and Pop. Exception occurs.

Comment: I can add all code that describe "compiled" foreach realization with try-finally block and loop by source, but it's make sample bigger.

Comment: @net without a meaningful example I can't comment - because tracking the exact stack state is key; I recommend you write **after every emit** what the stack should be. For example, search for `CreateParamInfoGenerator` here: https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs

Comment: @netdev k; I will try to look later